# Get Id of a Checkbox from a dynamic html table column using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

On my web page I created a Html table using 
**c# function**,

```
public String TableForView(DataTable ViewTable)
    {
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            if (ViewTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                html.Append("<table id='shTable' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>");

                html.Append("<thead>");
                html.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in ViewTable.Columns)
                {
                    html.Append("<th>");
                    html.Append(column.ColumnName);
                    html.Append("</th>");
                }
                html.Append("<th>");
                html.Append("Action & View");
                html.Append("</th>");
                html.Append("</tr>");
                html.Append("</thead>");
                html.Append("<tbody>");
                foreach (DataRow row in ViewTable.Rows)
                {
                    html.Append("<tr>");
                    foreach (DataColumn column in ViewTable.Columns)
                    {
                        html.Append("<td>");
                        html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                        html.Append("</td>");
                    }
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    html.Append("<input type='checkbox' id='" + row["AccNo"] + "' name='" + row["AccNo"] + "' class='ChBoxVal' checked=''>");
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                html.Append("</tbody>");
                html.Append("</table>");
            }
            else
            {
                html.Append("<h4>NO DATA AVAILABLE</h4>");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error_ManagerClass em = new Error_ManagerClass();
            em.WriteError(ex);
        }
        return (html.ToString());
    }
```

Now, I need to take a list of all checkbox id (if checked =true) as json string using jquery .
For that I tried using the following function to get the values

**jQuery**

```
var arrayOfValues = [];
        $('[id*=btnSave]').click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();

            var tableControl = document.getElementById("shTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for (var i = ((rows.length) - 1) ; i >= 1; i--) {
                var ChValue = document.getElementById("shTable").rows[i].cells[4].children[0].value;

                arrayOfValues = $('input:checkbox:checked', tableControl).map(function () {
                    return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:last').text();
                });
            }

        });
```

But this function is not returning any value. I am kind of new to jquery and I have no idea if this the right way to write jquery function...

Please help me with a solution or tell me where to look for this solution.

Comment: use `$(document).find('input:checkbox:checked')` for dynamic generated element

Comment: yah I tried, alert(arrayOfValues) is not showing anything..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select checkboxes using `input[type="checkbox"]` and filter only checked like this:

```js
var getChecked = function() {
  return $('#shTable').find('input[type="checkbox"]')
                      .filter(':checked')
                      .toArray()
                      .map(function(x) {
                         return $(x).attr('id');
                      });
}
$(document).on('click', '#getIds', function() {
  console.log(getChecked());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="shTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="1" type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="2" type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="3" type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="4" type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Four</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="getIds" type="button">Get ids</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each("#shTable tbody tr td input[type=checkbox]:checked",function(index,element){
    var $checkBox = $(element);
    var $checkBoxId  = $checkBox.attr('id');
    // you will get everything about the checkbox
});
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer for better understanding